# `any extends ` is Distributive Conditional Types and Generic conditional type resolves to never when the generic type is set to never

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
type A = [any] extends [never] ? true : false // false
type B = any extends never ? true : false //boolean
```

This makes me wonder, Why does' any extends' return a union type?

This is what the documentation explains:

`When conditional types act on a generic type, they become distributive when given a union type.` 
But I didn't apply the union type

This is also weird:

```
type IsNever<T> = T extends never ? true : false

type C = IsNever<never> // never

type D = never extends never ? true : false // true
```

Why just return `never`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the special handling of Typescript, when the generic is `any`, It will return a union type of `trueType` and `falseType`. When the generic is `never`, It will return `never` directly.